# How would I go about writing a program(python) to mimic the use of an AND Gate using Raspberry Pi

Tags: gpio, python, led

How I set up my breadboard:

- Placed SN74LS08N (AND gate) on a breadboard.
- Connected IC pin 7 to GND and IC pin 14 to 5 V for IC to get powered.
- Connected GPIO pin 16 to IC pin 13,
- Connected GPIO pin 12 to IC pin 12 and
- Connected GPIO pin SCLK to IC pin 11.
- Connected LEDs’ anode (+) to GPIO 12, 16 and SCLK,
- Connected LEDs’ cathode (-) to one end of resisters and
- Connected the other end of resisters to GND

I'm fairly new to Raspberry Pi and for some reason I cant wrap my head around how to write a python code to simulate an AND gate.

Comment: Hello @Vinx7, Welcome and nice to meet you.  Ah, let me see.  First, requirement and specification. (1) User requirement v0.1: "How to simulate TTL AND gate SN74LS08N using Rpi python", (2) Functional spec suggestion v0.1: "Input parameters: in1a, in1b, in2a, in2b, ... in4a, in4b  (b) Output parameters: out1y, ... out4y". Your comments and counter suggestions welcome.  Best Regards, Your sincerely, Ta and cheers.

Comment: Notes on Spec v0.1: We need to agree that we only want to simulate the logical input/output states. In other words, we will confine to function logical truth table (Table 1 of datasheet below). We don't care about power supply features, operating frequency and timing, temperature ranges etc. References: (1) SNx4HC08 Quadruple 2-Input Positive-AND Gates Datasheet - TI (Texas Instruments) 2016june: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc08.pdf.

Comment: We also need to agree on the use of technical terms: such as TTL/CMOS, Positive/Negative logic etc. I would suggest to follow "Electronics Tutorials".
(1) "Digital Logic GatesDigital Logic Gates - Eletronics-Tutorials": 
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/logic_1.html, https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/logic_2.html
(2) "Logic AND Gate Tutorial": https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/logic_2.html.

Comment: Hello. Rather than a list of connections it's much easier to understand the question if you include a schematic drawing -- there's a tool included for this, press Ctrl+M when editing to open it. I'm not clear what you want your Python code to do: exercise the two inputs to the AND gate you've connected and report back on it's output? Ignore the physical AND gate and simulate it's function on the GPIO?

Comment: A couple more questions... do you have three LEDs?  Pin 11 of your quad AND gate is an output.  What's the connection to SCLK for?  Or to ask another way, why is it not connected directly to an LED?

Comment: So we shall play with this little guy? https://imgur.com/gallery/zwP9HoH.

Comment: So I see you are connecting 2 GPIO pins to the A4, B4 input pins of the top left AND gate, and another GPIO pin to Q4 output pin, but I got stuck at the third last statement. How come you connect three GPIO output pins to the LED anode? I am afraid the newbie always goes wrong, say, setting two of the GPIO output pins to High, and the remaining GPIO output pin to LOW.  Then the two High guys join force to pull up the poor Low guy, which will melt down or blow up, ... and white smoke comes out - End-of-experiment !!!

Comment: I figured it out thanks for the help guys. It was with 2 LEDs

Comment: Thank you for you clarification. I am still confused because I am a picture guy, and must see the picture to understand what is going on.

Comment: I guess there should be 3 LEDs, as shown in this schematic: https://imgur.com/gallery/M2vxOHd. If you like, I can push this schematic to the open sky for everybody to watch, and you can press Ctrl-M to open you own drawing board, and drag it down to add your touches. Happy schematic drawing! Cheers. PS - The GPIO pin numbers got messed up. It is your home work to fix it!

Comment: So I have made my buggy schematic public: http://circuitlab.com/circuit/y88v6622yvzp/hc08_2020febn2802. You can leave comments and a wish list there, and hopefully other guys can help you. Of course you can also drag and drop it on your own StackExchange free of charge CircuitLabe drawing board. User guide: (1) <Ctrl> M to setup your own CircuitLab drawing board. (2) To keywaord "HC08" to search and drag my buggy schematic.